# Is this a separate site from gamedev.se?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I notice I have all the rep from my gamedev account, but none of the badges...? I'm confused. Is this (meta.gamedev) a separate site or not?

Is the rep linked all into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reputation is shared between "main" and "meta" versions of a site via (I believe) a process that transfers your main reputation to meta periodically. I've noticed it lags behind a few points sometimes.

Badges, however, are not shared between main and meta sites.

The rationale, in my mind, is that reputation is about what the community thinks of you and main and meta are part of the same community. Badges are for specific actions you've taken on the site interface, however, and thus are distinct. Possible odd exceptions are the Quorom-class badges on the main site, which are directly linked to actions you take on the meta site (and there's no such badge on the meta site itself).

Comment: Does it transfer back and forth? (synced)

Comment: That's really strange, lol.

Comment: Guess it's strange cause I would expect a separate repcount for the meta sites, like meta.SO has.

Comment: @ScottW Meta.SO is considered a special place on the network and is treated differently. It is effectively meta for the entire network.